# How to use JCrop and Django together?

Tags: python, django, image, crop, jcrop

Hey guys I am trying to let a user crop their profile picture when they upload it to a blog. right now I have JCrop doing this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#target').Jcrop({
      minSize: [100,100],
      aspectRatio: 1,
      setSelect: [10,10,100,100],
    });
});
```

My only problem is, I'm not sure how to integrate this with a django image upload, and then how to actually crop the image using django. Please help me! Thanks so much!